# Qiskit Aqua cannot import 'QasmQobj'

Tags: qiskit

I have an error when I use Quantum SVM kernel algorithm from Qiskit aqua.

This is my code section with imports:

```
from qiskit.qobj import (QasmQobj, QobjExperimentHeader,
                         QasmQobjInstruction, QasmQobjExperimentConfig, QasmQobjExperiment,
                         QasmQobjConfig)
```

And here is the error I obtain:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QasmQobj' from 'qiskit.qobj'
```

Comment: Qobj objects are usually bot needed by a end user. Why are you importing them?

Comment: Hi Zenab!  Welcome to QCSE!  Please make sure the title of your question is meaningful and not so overly broad as "Quantum Computing."  Also, it's helpful if you actually *have* a question to ask, at least one questio-mark.  It seems like your question is "can you help me with my error in Qiskit aqua?"  Please make an effort to format your question properly.

Comment: To complete @MarkS comment, please include **at least** the outputs of `python -V` and `python -m pip list`.

Comment: @Paul Nation, I don't import them , when I run project.py file to use QSVM, I have this error ImportError: cannot import name 'QasmQobj' from 'qiskit.qobj' 
 without import them.

Answer (score 1):

With the information you provided in your question, I recommand you to try to reinstall qiskit from scratch.

To do so, just execute

```
python -m pip install -U qiskit
```

I tried to execute your import statements after running this line, and it worked.

If you do not use the default `python`, replace `python` with the python executable you are using (e.g. `python3`). If you are on linux, `which python` will show you the executable hidden behind the `python` command.

If your problem is still here, please provide the output of the following commands (should always be provided in questions related to issues with python libraries):

```
python -V
python -m pip list
```

Comment: Dr. Nelimee, Python version              (base) C:\Users\Dell>python -V
              Python 3.7.3

Comment: Can you try `python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall qiskit`? This will force the reinstallation of your qiskit.

Comment: Ok, I 'll try it

Comment: Dr. Nelimee, I did it this command python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall qiskit and show with me this error  : cannot import name 'aqua_globals' from 'qiskit.aqua'

Comment: these packages of qiskit with versions after reinstallation--------------------->>                                                                               qiskit                         0.10.5
qiskit-aer                    0.2.1
qiskit-aqua                   0.5.2
qiskit-aqua-interfaces        0.1.0
qiskit-chemistry              0.5.0
qiskit-ibmq-provider          0.2.2
qiskit-ignis                  0.1.1
qiskit-terra                  0.8.2

Comment: I have the same versions, except for `qiskit-aqua-interface` which is not present on my installation. Why did you install from a .whl and not from the internet (PyPi)?

Comment: I installed qiskit, I downloaded this file  ( qiskit_aqua-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl ) from (https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-aqua/#files)  and excuted this command pip install C:\Users\qiskit_aqua-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: When I installed from pip install qiskit, showed me errors and I tried it from .whl

Comment: Dr. Nelimee ,could you advised me what the correct steps to run QSVM? and Many thanks in advance for your time and  your effort.

Comment: I do not know, I never used qiskit aqua... I would advise you to re-do the installation from scratch in a clean environment, but I don't know if it will solve your problem :/

Comment: Very Thanks ,Dr.Nelimee